# shell script works, alias fails. why?

Tags: bash, alias

I use a custom gnome-terminal profile for ssh sessions (different bg color provides a nice visual cue that I'm not working locally). Why doesn't my alias work?

This almost works, but the terminal window closes immediately.

```
alias myssh='gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=SSH -e "ssh $1"'
```

I tried using eval and mixing up the quotes, no change

```
alias myssh='eval gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=SSH -e "/usr/bin/ssh $1"'
alias myssh='gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=SSH -e \"/usr/bin/ssh $1\"'
alias myssh='eval gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=SSH -e \"/usr/bin/ssh $1\"'
alias myssh='gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=SSH -e \"/usr/bin/ssh $1\"'
```

Aliasing to a script in a file works great. What's the difference?

```
alias myssh='$HOME/bin/myssh.sh'

file:$HOME/bin/myssh.sh
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=SSH -e "ssh $1"
```

Answer (score 2):

In a script you have your arguments in $1 et al.

An alias is pretty much just text replacement, i.e. `myssh foo` will just turn in

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=SSH -e "ssh $1" foo
```

which is obviously wrong.

Just add your script to something like ~/bin.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` aliases do not take arguments. You can define a shell function instead:

```
myssh () {
    gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=SSH -e "ssh $1"
}
```